# Cannot create Service Fabric Cluster in Azure Portal

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azureportal

I can't start creating service fabric cluster. 
When starting creation portal always shows "Rainy Cloud" [image]and nothing can be inserted?

Comment: Does this happen when you simply click on "+ New" and then "Service Fabric Cluster"? If you hit F12 to pop up your browser dev tools, do you see any error messages or anything?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly the sequence. "+ New" -> Service Fabric Cluster.
On Console windows I found this error:
---------
MsPortalFx_1291247D38D480B3CD05D9CD5E758829D9966264.js:37 [Microsoft_Azure_ServiceFabric]  8:37:19 AM MsPortalFx/ViewModels/ViewModels.Part ViewModels.Part: Part's onInputsSet promise failed.
Error: message: Cannot read property 'subscriptionId' of undefined
stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscriptionId' of undefined
    at Object.parameterProvider.i.ViewModels.ParameterProvider.mapIncomingDataForEditScopeAsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, we found a problem in the portal that may be causing this. We'll be rolling out a fix in the next few days.

BTW, we have a repo on GitHub that you can use to report issues like this for a faster response: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues